# issues while exporting data from excel by using linqtoexcel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, import-from-excel

I am following this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel . But the problem now i am facing is ,my excel column name contains .,space etc characters. As per the mapping excel column name and property name should be same. If that is the case how can i insert special characters like . and space in property name. One more question is , is there any license issue regarding those dll's ,if i deploy it in somehwere?

**UPDATE**

Example of column name is `LOCATIONS.CONFIG 3G 2100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ExcelColumn` atrribute with your properties.

such as:

```
[ExcelColumn("Col.umn,Nam,e")] 
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Another way is using the `AddMapping` method:

```
ExcelQueryFactory qf = ...;
qf.TrimSpaces = TrimSpacesType.Both;
qf.AddMapping<SomeType>(o=>o.SomeProperty,"Col.umn,Nam,e")
```

Comment: Thanks got it, any license issues regarding those dlls

Comment: but for columnname LOCATIONS.CONFIG 3G 2100 ,it is giving null, why??

Comment: @peter  should work fine, make sure it does not have a trailing space

Comment: no trailing space , and no luck as of now, have you tried?

Comment: try using the `AddMapping` method of the `ExcelQueryFactory` rather than using attributes